# How can I use my own DD-WRT Wireless Router with a Virgin Media Hub?

Tags: router, home-networking

Does anyone know if it is possible to use a different Wifi Router (my Buffalo DD-WRT) instead of the Wifi on my Virgin Media Hub (not Super Hub).

I have seen people ask and get various vague answers on the net, but nothing concrete.

I've tried:

- Disabling Wifi and DHCP on the Virgin Router
- Enabling DHCP on my DD-WRT
- Connecting my PC to the DD-WRT (cabled)
- Connecting the Virgin Media Hub to the DD-WRT's WAN Port

But nothing worked, I could not see the internet or the Virgin Media Hub from PC or DD-WRT. So I had to factory reset the Virgin Media Hub.

I did have them on different Subnets. Virgin's IP is 192.168.0.1, DD-WRT's is 192.168.11.1. So that might have been the cause.

Comment: Does the Media Hub support bridge mode (modem mode)? If so, that would be the easiest way. If not -- what are the network settings of the DD-WRT if you do the following: disable WiFi on the Virgin router, enable DHCP on it, and connect the WAN port on the DD-WRT to one of the LAN ports on the Virgin router? To get the network settings, you can connect to the DD-WRT control panel by IP when a computer is connected to the DD-WRT wireless network, or easier, by cable to a DD-WRT LAN port.

Comment: just to make sure -- was the bridge mode (modem mode) what worked?

Comment: @lupincho - Modem mode doesn't exist. I just disabled Wifi on the Virgin Router, and pur both on the same Subnet (192.168.0.XXX) and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was:

- Disable Wifi on the Virgin Router.
- Set the Virgin Router's IP Address to 192.168.0.1.
- Set the DD-WRT's IP Address to 192.168.0.1.
- Both routers to 255.255.255.0 Subnet.
- I also found after a few day's I had to enter Virgin's DNS Server Addresses into the DD-WRT to get DNS working again.

Comment: Can you clarify what your settings are on both routers? Screenshots?